# Unit test case for the method having service dependency : Angular (karma)

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage

I have read so many article, still i see no result.
I have been trying to get the test case for the method having service dependency with no return value.

```
constructor(private _apiService:APIService){}
getData(){
     this._apiService.get('the URL', response=>{
         this.data = response
     }, err => {
         console.log(err.stack)
     })
}
```

I have the code in component ts as above. Since it's not returning anything I am not able to get the test code coverage, cover anything from the response. All the articles I have read are not able to cover the callback data.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-depending-on-services/#faking-service-dependencies Read that. The whole website is good for Angular unit testing.

Comment: I have but it doesn't address the issue that I am facing.